# Cannot connect SignalR client running on a port to a .NET Core 2.2 server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a .NET Core 2.2 server running locally on `http://localhost:5002` and a client (mostly copy/pasted from [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)) running on `http://localhost:5000`.

On the server side I have the sample hub from the docs, just renamed to `TestHub`, and the following bits in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSignalR(options => { options.EnableDetailedErrors = true; });
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ...

    app.UsePathBase("/custom");
    app.UseSignalR(routes => 
    {
        routes.MapHub<TestHub>("/test");
    });
    app.UseCors(options => options
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000")
        .AllowCredentials());
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The CORS config was adapted from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4483#issuecomment-445083271).

On the client side I installed the `@microsoft/signalr` package using the instructions from the docs, then slightly changed the `chat.js` file to use the server's url.

```
"use strict";

// This is the only line I changed
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:5002/test").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    ...
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    ...
});
```

I tried both `http://localhost:5002/test` and `http://localhost:5002/custom/test`, but nothing works. Chrome just says `net::ERR_FAILED`, while Firefox reports a `405` response for an `OPTIONS` call to `http://localhost:5002/test/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1`. Both browsers, however, warn that not `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present, which is odd since I was expecting the CORS config to take care of it.

Comment: On your ```CORS``` configuration add ```.SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));```

Comment: @Kiril1512 It unfortunately doesn't change anything. It seems that the server never returns an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I set the CORS config **before all other middleware** in the pipeline (such as `AddSignalR`) and it finally worked.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(...);

    // Everything else
}
```

Comment: This works without the ```.SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));``` method?

Comment: @Kiril1512 Yes, I just set `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000")` and it works (along with all the `AllowAny` stuff.

Comment: @Kiril1512 Remember to mark your answer as the answer if it did the trick :)

Comment: @Carsten The question was actually mine, I just ended up answering it myself after a few tries.

Comment: @Xzenon Yeah, I meant it as Kiril suggested. Its just so other people who see it in the future, knows this was what fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try using AddCors and Addpolicy from your ConfigureServices method instead. That solved the issue for me.

In ConfigureServices method add :

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder =>
            builder.WithOrigins(new[] {"http://localhost:5000", "https://localhost:5000"})
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true) //for signalr cors  
            );
```

And then first in Configure method add :

```
app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
```